# Why doesn't sizeof care about functions?

Tags: c++

Given the following, you'll see that x and y are the same size, but y has an additional function. What things are included in sizeof, and what things are not?

```
struct x
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
};
struct y
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    y(double q, double r, double s, double t) : a(q), b(r), c(s), d(t) {};
};
std::cout << sizeof(x)-sizeof(y) <<std::endl;
```

Comment: `y()` isn't virtual?

Comment: Data members contribute to the size of a struct, as each struct instance has its own complement of them; ordinary function members do not, as there is only one per struct type, and it is not contained within the struct.

Comment: Member functions can be viewed as almost the same as a free function that takes a reference to the class type as the first parameter.

Comment: Ah, so if there members with points, they don't contribute to the size?

Comment: @Justin - like self in python?

Comment: Imagine you had an array of 100 `struct y`'s. Would you need 100 copies of the compiled code for the function?

Comment: What did you research before asking here?

Comment: @walter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203162/what-does-sizeof-do
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...

Comment: A very similar question answered quite nicely is right here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504913/where-are-functions-of-an-object-stored-in-memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What things are included in sizeof, and what things are not?

`sizeof()` only includes things that have to be stored in memory as part of each instance of the type. (For a class or structure, it returns the amount of memory that needs to be allocated for an instance.)

Since the function is the same for every instance of `struct y`, it's not stored as part of the structure -- defining it there just allows the function to be called as a method on the structure. If it were a function pointer, though, the pointer would be part of the structure, and would contribute to its size.

Answer (score 2):

> **5.3.3 `Sizeof`                                                                                                         [expr.sizeof]**
> 1     The **`sizeof`** operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. 
>        The operand is
> either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a
>        parenthesized *type-id*. The **`sizeof`**
> operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>        function or incomplete type, to an enumeration
> type whose underlying type is not fixed
>        before all its enumerators have been declared, to the parenthesized
> name of such types, or to
>        a glvalue that designates a bit-field. **`sizeof(char)`**, **`sizeof(signed char)`** and
>
>        **`sizeof(unsigned char)`** are 1. The result of **`sizeof`** applied to any other fundamental type
>        (3.9.1) is
> implementation-defined. [ *Note*: in particular, **`sizeof(bool)`**,
>        **`sizeof(char16_t)`**, **`sizeof(char32_t)`**, and
> **`sizeof(wchar_t)`** are implementation-defined.<sup>75</sup>
>        — *end note* ] [ *Note*: See 1.7 for the definition of *byte*
> and 3.9 for the definition of *object
>        representation*. — *end note* ]
> 2     When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.
>        When applied
> to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class
>        including any padding required for
> placing objects of that type in an array. The size of a
>        most derived class shall be greater than zero (1.8).
> The result of applying **`sizeof`** to a base
>        class subobject is the size of the base class type.<sup>76</sup> When applied
> to an array, the result is
>        the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an array of *n*
> elements is *n*
>        times the size of an element.
> 3     The **`sizeof`** operator can be applied to a pointer to a function, but shall not be applied directly 
>        to a function.

<sup>*[C++ Online Working Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)*</sup>

In C++, no *sane* implementation would store a redundant copy the function's machine code within an object instance; not only would it be a massive waste of space, most architectures (that I'm aware of, anyway) don't allow you to mix machine code with data that way, so it doesn't contribute to the size of the object representation.